# Is it possible to query database using a variable as the model name?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a lot of models in one app. I need to iterate over them based on a corresponding value. So for example:

```
for x in dictionary:
    h = x.get() #line to get value from dictionary 
    q = h.objects.get(user=name)
```

Where h is the string variable name of the model and q is the desired query set

Comment: Is `dictionary` actually a dictionary? If so, then you can iterate through the keys and values using the `items()` method: `for key, value in dictionary.items()`.

Comment: @caseWestern please view my updated question

Answer (score 0):

You have to create additional dictionary that will map possible input strings to actual model classes, for example you want to query User model for string 'user'.  So you create models_mapping = {'user': User}. Then in loop,  you can write

```
model = models_mapping[h] 
q = model.objects.get(user=name)
```

It is not really clear what do you have in that dictionary and what is x.get(), but hopefully this will guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `get_model` method provided within django that can accomplish this. It can be used as follows:

```
def get_model(self, app_label, model_name, seed_cache=True):
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. It seems like it but I can’t figure out how to insert the get(user=user) part to output it as a query